# Draw the dots while mouse moves on the computer screen with python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, pixel

I have the following code which gives the corresponding mouse coordinates.

```
if(len(conts)==1):
    x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(conts[0])
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    cx=int(x+w/2)
    cy=int(y+h/2)
    cv2.circle(img,(cx,cy),int((w+h)/4),(0,0,255),2)
    pyautogui.moveTo(cx,cy)
```

**cx,cy** which gives the current coordinates of mouse.

**Question 1**

How do I draw dots in the screen while mouse moves over the screen?

---

**Question 2**

How do I draw a shape and save it as a .jpeg format image?

```
os : windows 10
python version : Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
```

Comment: We need a lot more information before we can help - which operating system are you using? What version of Python? Do you have experience with any Graphical User Interface (GUI) frameworks?

Comment: google for `cv2.setMouseCallback`

Comment: @JBRWilkinson i have worked in pyQt and Qt Designer